# Lightning component flexipageRegionInfo

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

What values does Lightning use to make the Small, Medium, Large, and Xlarge width determination?

[Make Your Lightning Page Components Width-Aware with lightning:flexipageRegionInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_width_aware.htm)

There is nothing specified here:

[Flexipage Region Info](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:flexipageRegionInfo/documentation)

Answer (score 2):

**Added based on comments**

As a standard you get only 4 values as stated. If you want to render based on custom width/height, you can use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

The Media Queries Level 4 specification includes some syntax improvements to make media queries using features that have a "range" type, for example width or height, less verbose. Level 4 adds a range context for writing such queries. For example, using the max- functionality for width we might write the following:

```
@media (max-width: 30em) { ... }
```

In Media Queries Level 4 this can be written as:

```
@media (width <= 30em) { ... }
```

Using min- and max- we might test for a width between two values like so:

```
@media (min-width: 30em) and (max-width: 50em) { ... }
```

This would convert to the Level 4 syntax as:

```
@media (30em <= width <= 50em ) { ... }
```

Media Queries Level 4 also adds ways to combine media queries using full boolean algebra with and, not, and or.

---

**OLD**

You need not worry about the values used by [flexipageRegionInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_width_aware.htm). Just note that it will return the values ***SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE, or XLARGE***

Below is the sample:

**COMPONENT**:

```
<aura:attribute name="width" type="String"/>
<lightning:flexipageRegionInfo width="{!v.width}"/>

width = {!v.width}
```

> `lightning:flexipageRegionInfo` will set the value of `width` which
>   will be set on attribute because of **2-way data binding**

Now put this component in different regions of flexipage to verify.

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: The problem I have is that I'm trying to render the elements in a component differently when the size is less than MEDIUM, but not SMALL.

Comment: @salesforce-sas Not sure if your updated answer is relevant here, because media queries deal with screen size, not element/container size into which the component was dropped. I was wondering the same thing as OP, since if you do a determination of what `SMALL` is in comparison to `MEDIUM`, you would also have to define a breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

The values are based on template metadata.

See this doc how it is declared in custom templates - the standard templates have the same defined: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_template_component.htm